# Formal optimization of strategy in proof-writing?

Tags: logic, optimization

I'm currently introducing myself to formal logic--recently, this question popped into my head. (I'll be referencing [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/) for notation.)

Given a logical deduction system $H$, suppose we wish to show that some formula $\varphi$ is deducible from $H$ given some set of premises $X$. Doing so goes as follows: we construct a finite sequence $\psi_0, \psi_1, ..., \psi_n$ with each $\psi_i$ either an axiom of $H$, an element of $X$, or following from the previous $i$ formulas by an inference rule of $H$.

Now, we don't know whether $\varphi$ *is* deducible in $H$, but suppose we want approach our proof of $\varphi$ in such a way that minimizes $n$ (if we do manage to complete the proof). **Question:** Are there cases when we can explicitly determine the most "efficient" choice of $\psi_0$? Can this strategy be generalized or is it impossible?

(Of course, the answer to this question depends on how one defines "efficiency". My next question would then be: Has this kind of research been done before? I can't find any papers on this specific topic.)

Thanks in advance!